# jquery slide down many images in sequence one by one after page load

Tags: jquery, animation, slidedown, slideup

I am trying to display images with sliding effects(top to bottom of the page) one by one in to on page load. After going through so many sites I did not get any plug-in related to this functionality. Here is the example link of what i exactly want http://kyan.com/
Here when you click on the next arrow link, it would at first slide up existing images then I slide down new images. I wants the same functionality as working on http://kyan.com/, but I have to slide image one by one only at page load(no any next prev link).

If any one know such related plug-in name, then plz let me know the name of it?
Or is there any custom code you have regarding this.

Thanks in advance for advice/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this site jquery [custom jquery Animation](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/18/custom-animation-banner/) modifying this code will help..

hope this helps

Comment: hi,  The script was very nice, but I does't resolve my problem. Well Thx for the reply :)